# Arma 2 CD Key Problems

Tags: steam, arma-2

So, my Arma 2 Operation Arrowhead of steam is banned (battleye/cd key ban).
If I buy Arma 2 Arrowhead and Dayz on the humble bundle then add it onto steam, will it reset my cd key to the one I just bought or just keep my default?

Answer (score 1):

Steam will not issue a new key if you purchase it or redeem it on the same account. When this happened with me (I was stupid and got my key stolen), I ended up buying it through Amazon instead. Redeeming it through a new Steam account should work though, since the CD Key is per-account.

Answer (score 0):

Arma 2 and Arma 2: OA are very insecure games if you ask me. I, myself, had my CD key stolen just buy playing on a "hacked" DayZ server. To answer your question directly, no you can not add two of the same games on the same account. However, you can make a new account and add your CD key to that account. This may be more beneficial to you as some server owners will ban players by their Steam ID.

As a side note, if you had your CD key stolen or you think you were banned unjustly, you can contact Bohemia Interactive's support e-mail and let them know what happened. If you provide them with all the needed information then you will receive a new CD key for both games. Be aware, when you email them to tell them your situation, they will email you back asking for your IP address, username, and a few other things that you will need. Hope you can get your issue fixed.

P.S. Sorry for not putting any links. I am currently on my school campus and they have Bohemia Interactive's website blocked. I'm sure that you'll be able to find them though.